# bootstrap.yml configuration not processed anymore with Spring Cloud 2020.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

In my [Spring Boot project](https://github.com/pavankjadda/HashiCorpVault-SpringCloud), I defined 4 profiles

1. demo
2. dev
3. test
4. prod

properties in YAML files will be replaced by HashiCorp Vault properties during startup. For this, I use Spring Cloud Vault library. Everything works as expected in Spring Boot 2.3.x

When I try to upgrade the project to Spring Boot 2.4.0 with Spring Cloud Vault 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT version, the properties are not being replaced

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    vault:
      authentication: APPROLE
      app-role:
        role-id: ${role-id}
        secret-id: ${secret-id}
        role: pres-read
        app-role-path: approle
      uri: ${vault-server}
      connection-timeout: 5000
      read-timeout: 15000
      kv:
        enabled: true
        backend: secret
        application-name: app/pres
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: 'demo'
```

**application-demo.yml**

```
## Server Properties
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  datasource:
    username: ${pres.db.username}
    password: ${pres.db.password}
    url: ${pres.db.url}
```

**Spring Cloud Vault Library**

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Error Log:**

```
/Users/jaddap2/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adopt-openj9-11.0.9/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:59487,suspend=y,server=n -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.profiles.active=demo -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Drole_id=49c8d8fb-1bdd-7f3b-493f-a11e20907a62 -Dsecret_id=a7ee91cc-e259-82ff-2b34-5c333dda300c -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:/Users/jaddap2/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.2/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/jaddap2/IdeaProjects/HashiCorpVault-SpringCloud/target/classes:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.4.0/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.4.0.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.4.0/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.4.0.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.3.1/spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.6/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.4.0/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.4.0.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/3.4.5/HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.3.1/spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/jakarta/transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/1.3.3/jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.23.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.24.0-GA/javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.18/byte-buddy-1.10.18.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.1.3.Final/jandex-2.1.3.Final.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/dom4j/dom4j/2.1.3/dom4j-2.1.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.2.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.3/jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/2.3.3/txw2-2.3.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.11/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.4.1/spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.4.1/spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/5.3.1/spring-orm-5.3.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.3.1/spring-context-5.3.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.3.1/spring-tx-5.3.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.1/spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.3.1/spring-aspects-5.3.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.4.0/spring-boot-starter-web-2.4.0.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.4.0/spring-boot-starter-2.4.0.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.4.0/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.4.0.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.13.3/log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.13.3/log4j-api-2.13.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.30/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.27/snakeyaml-1.27.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.4.0/spring-boot-starter-json-2.4.0.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.3/jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.11.3/jackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.11.3/jackson-core-2.11.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.11.3/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.11.3/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.11.3/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.11.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.4.0/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.4.0.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.39/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jakarta.el/3.0.3/jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.39/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.3.1/spring-web-5.3.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.1/spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.3.1/spring-expression-5.3.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-vault-config/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-starter-vault-config-3.0.0-20201123.200715-420.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.15/commons-codec-1.15.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.13/httpcore-4.4.13.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-starter-3.0.0-20201123.160603-486.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-context/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-context-3.0.0-20201123.160522-488.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/5.4.1/spring-security-crypto-5.4.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-commons/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-commons-3.0.0-20201123.160533-486.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-rsa/1.0.9.RELEASE/spring-security-rsa-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.64/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.64.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.64/bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-vault-config/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-vault-config-3.0.0-20201123.200557-420.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/vault/spring-vault-core/2.3.0-M1/spring-vault-core-2.3.0-M1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.4.0/spring-boot-devtools-2.4.0.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.4.0/spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.4.0/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.0.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.22/mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/2.4.0/spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.4.0.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.16/lombok-1.18.16.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.1/spring-core-5.3.1.jar:/Users/jaddap2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.3.1/spring-jcl-5.3.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar com.pj.vaultdemo.VaultDemoApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59487', transport: 'socket'
{spring.web.resources.chain.cache=false, spring.web.resources.cache.period=0}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.0)

2020-11-24 14:57:53.788  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] com.pj.vaultdemo.VaultDemoApplication    : Starting VaultDemoApplication using Java 11.0.9 on macOsMachine with PID 95795 (/Users/jaddap2/IdeaProjects/HashiCorpVault-SpringCloud/target/classes started by jaddap2 in /Users/jaddap2/IdeaProjects/HashiCorpVault-SpringCloud)
2020-11-24 14:57:53.792  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] com.pj.vaultdemo.VaultDemoApplication    : The following profiles are active: demo
2020-11-24 14:57:53.895  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-11-24 14:57:53.895  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-11-24 14:57:54.904  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-11-24 14:57:54.962  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 48 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-11-24 14:57:55.300  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=80a5ef39-fa0c-39ac-928e-c0ba95b06c78
2020-11-24 14:57:56.347  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2020-11-24 14:57:56.358  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-11-24 14:57:56.359  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-11-24 14:57:56.490  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-11-24 14:57:56.491  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2594 ms
2020-11-24 14:57:56.580  WARN 95795 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$JpaInvokerConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
2020-11-24 14:57:56.585  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-11-24 14:57:56.627  INFO 95795 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-11-24 14:57:56.661 ERROR 95795 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$JpaInvokerConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:429) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1780) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$247/000000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1161) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.pj.vaultdemo.VaultDemoApplication.main(VaultDemoApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$247/000000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$JpaInvokerConfiguration.init(RefreshAutoConfiguration.java:131) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0-20201123.160522-488.jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$247/000000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfUnique(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2050) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.getDataSourceInitializer(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:98) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:61) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:121) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DatabaseDriver.fromJdbcUrl(DatabaseDriver.java:283) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:229) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:176) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 58 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59487', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: There's no bootstrap context anymore so that `bootstrap.yml` isn't read and processed.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I just checked Spring Cloud Vault docs, I still see it being used https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/#_approle_authentication

Comment: @StephaneNicoll Are the references to bootstrap.properties at https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_client_side_usage  still relevant?  Following this doens't seem to be working for me, spring.application.name is not getting set

Comment: @StephaneNicoll Additionally, are there any sort of release notes that we can check for when upgrading to save hours of time debugging configuration issues?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

As pointed put by Nicoll, With Spring Cloud Vault 3.0 and Spring Boot 2.4, the bootstrap context initialization (`bootstrap.yml`, `bootstrap.properties`) of property sources was **deprecated**. This can be fixed in one of the 2 ways

1. Use Spring Boot 2.4.0 Config Data API to import configuration from Vault (Preferred)
2. Legacy Processing: Enable the bootstrap context either by setting the configuration property `spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true` or by including the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**1. Use Spring Boot 2.4.0 Config Data API  (Preferred)**

Move **bootstrap.yml** configuration to **application.yml** and updated file looks like below

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    vault:
      authentication: APPROLE
      app-role:
        role-id: ${role-id}
        secret-id: ${secret-id}
        role: pres-read
        app-role-path: approle
      uri: ${vault-server}
      connection-timeout: 5000
      read-timeout: 15000
  config:
    import: vault://secret/app/pres/
```

And define individual profiles as shown below. Add `spring.config.import: vault://secret/app/pres/demo` property.

**application-demo.yml**

```
## Server Properties
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  config:
    import: vault://secret/app/pres/demo
  datasource:
    username: ${pres.db.username}
    password: ${pres.db.password}
    url: ${pres.db.url}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Repeat the same process for all profiles like dev, test, qc, staging and prod.

**2. Legacy Processing:**

Add the following dependency if you still want to use `bootstrap.yml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to the project. The issue will be resolved.

See [Spring Cloud Vault docs](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/tree/v3.0.0-M5) for more information

Comment: or `spring.config.import: vault://`

Comment: @spencergibb I tried to use that property but the properties are not being replaced. I moved vault config to `application.yml file` and you can see it here https://github.com/pavankjadda/HashiCorpVault-SpringCloud/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi @PavanJadda Have you implemented any Vault Agent for client side to manage tokens and secretId. i'm uisng Vault Transit for encoding/decoding data

Comment: @RameshKanuganti I have no idea what you are talking about. I am using vault with Spring Boot application and pass role id, secret id during start up.

Comment: @spencergibb I updated the answer. Please edit it, if I missed anything.

Comment: Hello @PavanJadda Just saw your answer and that bootstrap is now deprecated.

I have a bootstrap configuration that uses Consul to create a custom property source but I have many customizations (allowing including configuration files by consul path,  override of properties, variables, etc).

What should I do to get this working with new Spring Boot Cloud without using the bootstrap starter?

Thanks.

Comment: @LucasSoares I would suggest you to create a new issue with details of your configuration

Comment: Why dod they still have [in the official docs](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-vault) the use of `bootstrap.yml` then!?

Comment: @tfrascaroli Looks like they haven't updated the page

Comment: @PavanJadda - Can you pls guid me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72152159/spring-boot-v2-6-7-and-hashicoprt-vault-integration-issue-unable-to-fetch-the-d?

Answer (score 39):

I spent a whole day trying to resolve this issue.
For everyone who is following any outdated cloud tutorials:- from springboot 2.4 bootstrap starter dependency has to be added, to follow along the tutorial to use bootstrap.properties (bootstrap.yml) for external configuration.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well, My second approach(Legacy Processing) says same thing

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following configuration

```
<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
```

---

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

---

And Bootstrap.properties

```
spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true
spring.config.vault.enabled=true
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled=true

spring.application.name=vaultdemo
spring.cloud.vault.host=localhost
spring.cloud.vault.port=8200
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http
spring.cloud.vault.uri=http://localhost:8200
spring.cloud.vault.authentication=TOKEN
spring.cloud.vault.token=<token>
spring.cloud.vault.generic.backend=<secret>
spring.cloud.vault.connection-timeout=5000
spring.cloud.vault.read-timeout=15000
spring.config.import=vault://<secret>/<application>
```

It is working for me