# Spring boot is not loading bootstrap.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I noticed that when I create a spring-cloud application it is only getting properties from the `application.properties` file (or `application.yml`), so I have created the following demo project to simplify the situation, however, I still couldn't manage to load properties from a `bootstrap.propertiles` file.
I tried converting the bootstrap.properties file into bootstrap.yml with the same result.
I tried compiling and running the microservice as standalone with the same result.

I left this project on GitHub to demonstrate the situation: https://github.com/bcfernandez/Mobile-app-ws.git

- The only entry point available is http://localhost:port/users/status
- `application.properties` file is empty.
- `bootstrap.properties` file sets `server.port` as 8181.
- The application is running on port 8080.

The `pom.xml` is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>es.myorg.trm.api.users</groupId>
    <artifactId>TRM_ApiUsers</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TRM_ApiUsers</name>
    <description>TRM API for Users Management</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>                   
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.9</version>
        </dependency>  
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Why is this simple project is not working as expected?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64994034/bootstrap-yml-configuration-not-processed-anymore-with-spring-cloud-2020-0/65445282#65445282
thanks @BCF for mentioning the link in comments it actually answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your pom file, you are not creating any springboot cloud project because typically you will find a corresponding Spring Cloud BOM version in pom.xml if you used https://start.spring.io/, like so

```xml
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

That's why the bootstrap file is being dismissed.
[Here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) is a number of spring cloud projects you can use.

You can start by:

A. creating a spring cloud config server project

B. Make your actual project the spring cloud config client
here is the official [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/)

Sorry If I'm not understanding your question properly, but if you are already created a springcloud project, one possible issue is the version...

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64994034/bootstrap-yml-configuration-not-processed-anymore-with-spring-cloud-2020-0/65445282#65445282) similar issue was raised on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That section in the pom.xml is already there.

Comment: Sorry I rechecked and It did NOT have any cloud project in it

Comment: The issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64994034/bootstrap-yml-configuration-not-processed-anymore-with-spring-cloud-2020-0/65445282#65445282 has been indeed very useful. Even creating the pom.xml using https://start.spring.io the necessary dependency to activate the bootstrap context was missing. Thanks a LOT.