# Spring Cloud Vault: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault

**Hi everyone**

I created a program to test the vault with start.spring.io. And I configure the vault in the **bootstap.properties** file like this:

```
spring.application.name=vault-test
spring.cloud.vault.uri=http://localhost:8200
spring.cloud.vault.token=MY_ROOT_TOKEN
```

Here is my **pom.xml** configuration:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Also, the **vault development server** is pre-set up with the following command:

```
vault server -dev
```

But when I run the program, it has the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate]: Factory method 'vaultTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultSessionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultSessionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientAuthentication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication]: Factory method 'clientAuthentication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty
```

But the vault token is set in the **bootstrap.properties** file !. But the strangest thing for me is that when I set the token in the application.properties file, I will not have an error! I know the **bootstrap.properties** file is called before the **application properties** file is called, and the token must be set in it, but why does the vault not notice it?

Comment: did you resolve the error?

Answer (score 2):

With Spring Boot 2.4, the bootstrap context initialization(bootstrap.yml, bootstrap.properties) of property sources is deprecated.
Please refer below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65009480

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `spring-cloud-starter` dependency ( which should be added if you select the `Cloud Bootstrap` dependency on start.spring.io .

Just add the following dependency in your pom.xml file :

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no! I still have the same error.