# spring-cloud-vault-config-databases with Spring Boot 2.4.0 Config Data API fails to bind properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-vault-config

I'm using **spring-cloud-vault-config-databases** with Spring Boot 2.4.0 Config Data API as the prefered mode described here [bootstrap.yml configuration not processed anymore with Spring Cloud 2020.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64994034/bootstrap-yml-configuration-not-processed-anymore-with-spring-cloud-2020-0) :

1. When I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.0 Config Data API to import configuration from Vault (Preferred) the secret properties are not binded to the spring.datasource.username & spring.datasource.password and my postgres cnx fails.
2. When I'm using "Legacy Processing" with the **bootstrap** configuration property **spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true** the properties spring.datasource.username & spring.datasource.password are well binded to my Vault secret.

What is the expected behaviour of the **spring-cloud-vault-config-databases** ?
Is expected to works with Spring Boot 2.4.0 Config Data API ?

my application.yml

```
spring.cloud.vault:
  enabled: true
  authentication: CERT
  ssl:
    key-store: file: ...
    key-store-password: ...
    trust-store: ...
    trust-store: ...
    trust-store-password: ...
    cert-auth-path: ...
  uri: https:...
  namespace: ...
  fail-fast: true

  database:
    enabled: true
    role: myPostgresRole
    backend: database/postgres/...
    username-property: spring.datasource.username
    password-property: spring.datasource.password    

spring:
  config:
    import: vault://secret/... , vault://database/postgres/...
```

Versions used :

spring-boot : 2.4.11

spring-cloud : 2020.0.3

spring-cloud-vault-config-databases : 3.0.3

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/65009480/390462